# Passing the value of an html element as a parameter in ember

Tags: javascript, html, templates, ember.js

I am sorry if this is a dumb question, but I just can't seem to figure it out. I need to pass the value of the row element to the function it calls, but I can't seem to access the value. I can't give the row a unique id, because my process of adding rows to the table involves duplicating the row and altering its value. Here is my code:

```
    <tr value = "0" onmouseover={{action 'displayBar' this.value}}>

          //     ^ This is the value I am trying to pass      ^ This is how I am trying to pass it
```

I have tried this.value, value="target.value", value, etc. but all come out to undefined. The only way I have got the parameter to be undefined is if I just sent "0" as the parameter instead of this.value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`target.value` will only work for `input` elements. `value` is not an HTML attribute for elements other than `input`, so the target does not have a `value` property equal to the attribute.

You can instead pass the entire target like this:

```
<tr data-value=0 onmouseover={{action 'displayBar' value="target"}}>
```

and then in your js:

```
actions: {
  displayBar(target) {
    const value = target.getAttribute('data-value');
  }
}
```

Here is a working Ember Twiddle: https://ember-twiddle.com/c177c2be6f7d740968e2f02f79748d83?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C
(Just hover over the "Lots of stuff")

Comment: You are definitely on the right track, but target.getAttribute('data-value') keeps returning null for me. Any clue why?

Answer (score 0):

does this work:

```
<tr onmouseover={{action 'displayBar' 0}}>
```

?

Comment: Yes, that successfully passes 0 as a parameter, however, this does not work for me because I have to be able to dynamically add rows to the table. I want each row to pass its respective index as the parameter. When creating new rows, the process involves duplicating the last row and just incrementing that row's value, allowing me to still call this action for each specific row.

Comment: why not dynamically adjust what parameters you're passing to action? just make the rows components

Comment: You know what? That's actually a great idea, thank you! I'm fairly new to ember so this idea just completely slipped my mind.

Comment: feel free to join the ember discord https://discordapp.com/invite/zT3asNS lots of people to ask questions. :)